# Use sudo in conjunction with regular user's private SSH key

Tags: ssh, sudo, ssh-keys

As the **ubuntu** user, I want to execute a command which requires root privileges so I use `sudo` like this:

```
sudo puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
```

This command invokes SSH and prompts me for a password, despite my public key being authorized on the remote host. The only way I can get it to work is if I add my private SSH key to the root user.

I don't want to add my private key to the root user. How can I use `sudo` but still use the private key for the **ubuntu** user?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/a/118932/155817) answer over on Server Fault. Essentially, you need to add this line to `/etc/sudoers` (use `visudo`):

```
Defaults    env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

You should then be able to runt your command normally:

```
sudo puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: @jamjam Try `sudo -E` and also try some of the other solutions on the linked answer.

Answer (score -1):

It turn's out there was a pretty simple solution to this.

Adding a -u option allows me to specify a user.

```
sudo -u $USER puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
```

Now the ssh key for that user will be used.

Comment: This makes no sense, the `-u` option allows you to specify what user you're acting as. `sudo -u $USER command` is the same as running `command`